# How can I see all object in Xcode

Tags: object, xcode6, instruments

I create a easy App for mac in Objective-C and I want to see all object and variable. Include destroyed and persistent object.
I know instruments, but I can not find how to see this information.

thank for help.

Comment: What do you want to see that Instruments does not show you when you use its allocations template?

Comment: No I don't understand how to use allocations template for this! I view lots of things exempted my variable and object!